# SwiftUI ! How to change the Bool value from One View to Another View

Tags: swift, swiftui

Good afternoon!
I have two Views
LoginView and ProfileView

LoginView has a number of values:

```
@State private var email: String = "Email"
@State private var password: String = "Password"
@State private var showToggleSignup: Bool = false
@State private var showToggleLogin: Bool = true
@State private var showToggleReset: Bool = false
@State private var show Profile View: Bool = false
```

These values are changed by clicking on various buttons in the LoginView itself for example by:

```
Button {
     showToggleLogin.toggle()
     showToggleReset.toggle()
} label: {
     Gradient Button(text: "forgot pass?")
         .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
         .opacity(showToggleLogin ? 0 : 1)
 }
```

How can I change these values for LoginView while in Profile View?

I would really appreciate your help!

I need to change the showProfile in View 2 from false to true while in View 1

Maybe I don't understand something, but I'm just learning!

Comment: Put the `@State` at the top. most common `View` then pass it down with `@Binding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an @State variable in one view and you want it changed in another view, you define the variable as an @Binding in that other view and pass it on.

So in the login view you have:

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @State private var showToggleSignup: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        ProfileView(showToggleSignp: $showTogglesignup)
    }
}
```

Then the profile view looks like:

```
struct ProfileView: View {

    @Binding var showToggleSignup: Bool

    var body: some View {
        // Do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

Good luck,
MacUserT

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of variables like above you can also bundle them in an Observed Object, a class which conforms to the ObservableObject protocol. There you @Publish the variables. Use .enviroment to bypass these object or declare the Object with @EnviromentObject. There are a lot of tutorials for that out there, like

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject